# Is it possible to manage backups from SolrJ?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I can create / restore Solr backups from Solr via `CollectionAdminRequest.Backup` and `CollectionAdminRequest.Restore`.

Looks like it's possible via http api, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/replication?command=details&wt=xml
```

But is it possible to list all backups and drop one by name from SolrJ?

I'm using Solr 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found, it's **not possible** to do it from SolrJ directly.

So I've ended up working with HDFS directly. I've configured Solr to use HDFS as backup storage. And from my code I'm accessing it via HDFS client - I can list and remove backups from it.